# Magento 2 (2.0.7) How to edit a a .php file from module-theme for your own theme?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0.7

I want to adjust the header menu. It works a bit by editing topmenu.phtml, at least for the $outermostClass to add some classes but I think $childrenWrapClass has an error since in function _addSubMenu in topmenu.php it does not use the var.

Though anyway, I would need more than adding a class to submenus. I would need to make the links look like

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
```

So I would need to edit topmenu.php in any way.

How to edit the topmenu.php? It is located originally in module-theme/Block/Html/Topmenu.php

Can I place it in my theme directory somewhere simply?

Someone mentioned I would need to create a module for it. Does that mean creating a directory on the same level of Magento_Theme in my theme directory? If so then how to name that directory and where to place my topmenu.php in order to use this instead the original one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create module for changes in **Topmenu.php** file,

File path is : **`app/code`**

Create module name `Package/Topmenu/registration.php`,

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Package_Topmenu',
    __DIR__
);
```

`Package/Topmenu/etc/module.xml`,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Package_Topmenu" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

Create `di.xml` file for override topmenu file,

filepath is `Package/Topmenu/etc/di.xml`,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Package\Topmenu\Block\Topmenu"/>
</config>
```

Create block for override topmenu file function,
`Package/Topmenu/Block/Topmenu.php`,

```
<?php

namespace Package\Topmenu\Block;

class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{
     //override core function here..

}
```

Run command , `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Clear cache and check now its overrider core block.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I was wondering about some things. In my magento 2.0.7 there is only a app/design and a app/etc directory. Is the app/code path still correct or is it from some earlier magento version?

Comment: You have to just create folder inside app folder with name code, by default code folder is not available

Comment: Thank you! And regarding the directory names Package and Topmenu, are those to be taken in order to override or in order to easily recognize or can I use directories like vendor/themename since it is only for a theme?
I wonder if it would not make sense for magento devs to include only theme modules into a theme directory directly too.

Comment: working for you now or not?

Comment: I'm on it. Need to do the setup:upgrade now... php tags don't need closing tags anymore? didn't know that.

Comment: yeah, its not required to close

Comment: I did it now though it seems the setup:upgrade has a problem. It shows
/web/m20/bin$ php magento setup:upgrade

  [Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

setup:upgrade [--keep-generated] [--magento-init-params="..."]

though php magento deploy:mode:show works fine and showing dev mode

Comment: Ok, it seems I have Loaded Configuration File => /opt/phpfcgi-5.6.22/lib/php.ini with php -i | grep 'php.ini' but Loaded Configuration File /var/www/conf/web1203/php.ini so there is a difference.
I don't have a clue how to solve this.

Comment: The files are the same now though the error still is there. Guess I need to do some more troubleshooting. :/

Comment: I found a workaround since I could not solve it. I added 'Package_Topmenu' => 1, in config.php under app/etc. Unfortunately my website now is blank. :D not a single sign in sourcecode anymore. Anyway... a step forward it seems.

Comment: Hey Rakesh, finally today I got it running, after fixing a good bunch of errors with the server. Though now the menu vanished completely. When I put an error into topmenu.php then I get a blank page so the php is drawn. And extends should only mean that the old class is not overwritten but that I can replace some of it's functions I think. But still it does not matter what I put into. Even if it is the whole classcode from original php. Any idea where the problem might lie?

Comment: I'm a noob you see so I only now realized the error message in system.log. I checked before but did not see one. But then: [2016-06-26 20:28:34] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'html/topmenu.phtml' in module: 'Package_Topmenu' block's name: 'catalog.topnav' [] []
I found it is a mag-bug from https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4564

Comment: I'm a noob you see so I only now realized the error message in system.log. I checked before but did not see one. But then: [2016-06-26 20:28:34] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'html/topmenu.phtml' in module: 'Package_Topmenu' block's name: 'catalog.topnav' [] []
I found it is a mag-bug from https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4564
The solution for now is binding my template with <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600"/> the solution. The rest works now finally. :P
It didn't let me edit...